# Python - Does Python support pointer or not?

Tags: python, opencv

I **know** that python **does not** support pointers! But recently I've noticed something about OpenCV-python! The following line will draw a circle on a given image with the specified center and radius,

`cv2.circle(image, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 00), thickness=3)`

according to the [cv2.circle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#circle) doc, the return value is `None`. So all the changes happen on the given image. But we know that python doesn't support pointers! So if it is possible to do so, how!? Does any one can help or provide a link!

Comment: are you worried about the img getting manipulated ?

Comment: No, I want to know if it is possible to have pointers how we can use this tool in other applications!

Comment: You wud definitely want to read this [ Semantics of Python variable names from a C++ perspective](http://rg03.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/semantics-of-python-variable-names-from-a-c-perspective/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, python does not have *pointers*, but the objects are passed to functions *by reference* (and so in java, another language without pointers). This mechanism is very similar to passing pointers by value in C.

The variable `image` is merely a reference to an object, NOT the object itself. When you pass `image` to the function `cv2.circle`, you actually pass the reference *by value*. It is the local copy of the reference in the function, but they essentially *point to* the same object in memory. That's how `image` gets modified in `cv2.circle`.

Suggested reading: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

and [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) (thanks, @Wooble!)

Comment: Python does not use pass by reference. At least not in the way that term is usually understood. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference has a lot of good answers)

Comment: @Wooble pass by reference is certainly a case of pass by value :)
and that's a great resource!

Comment: @0606002 Passing a reference by value is different from the "Pass by reference". Pass by reference would require reassignments of parameters in the called function to cause reassignments in the caller as well. This is the semantic that C++ uses for pass by reference and is not what python does.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the [evaluation strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Strict_evaluation) article on wikipedia.

Python does [call by sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) (which is a synonym of saying: passes a reference to the object by value)

I don't think I would be able to explain it better than the way those articles do.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't give you access to pointers when you code.  You can't declare a pointer, but of course it used pointers internally.

The language doesn't have pointers, but the implementation uses pointers.